# How can I prevent overlapping plotly graphs in a shiny Rmd?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, ggplotly

Given a `shiny` `r-markdown` report with reactive `plotly` plots, how do I prevent long plots (produced with `ggplotly`) from overlapping?

In the example it is evident that the plot produced in the `plotly-long` chunk is overlapped by the plot produced in the chunk below.

````
---
title: "A shiny Report"
runtime: shiny
output:
  bookdown::html_document2
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(type =  c("potato", "carrot", "leek"),
                 count = c(1, 3, 2))
```

```{r, results="asis"}
selectizeInput("SELECTION",
               "Choose:",
               selected = c("potato", "leek"),
               multiple = TRUE,
               choices = c("potato", "carrot", "leek"))
```

```{r, filter-data}
df_filt <- reactive({
  df %>%
    filter(type %in% input$SELECTION)
})
```

```{r make-ggplot}
ggp <- reactive({
  df_filt() %>%
    ggplot(aes(y = count, fill = type, x = "a_bar")) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
})
```

```{r plotly-long}
renderPlotly({
  ggplotly(ggp(), height = 1600)
})
```

```{r plotly-normal}
renderPlotly({
  ggplotly(ggp())
})
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `renderPlotly` with `renderUI` does the trick.

````
---
title: "A shiny Report"
runtime: shiny
output:
  bookdown::html_document2
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(type =  c("potato", "carrot", "leek"),
                 count = c(1, 3, 2))
```

```{r, results="asis"}
selectizeInput("SELECTION",
               "Choose:",
               selected = c("potato", "leek"),
               multiple = TRUE,
               choices = c("potato", "carrot", "leek"))
```

```{r, filter-data}
df_filt <- reactive({
  df %>%
    filter(type %in% input$SELECTION)
})
```

```{r make-ggplot}
ggp <- reactive({
  df_filt() %>%
    ggplot(aes(y = count, fill = type, x = "a_bar")) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
})
```

```{r plotly-long}
renderUI({
  ggplotly(ggp(), height = 1600)
})
```

```{r plotly-normal}
renderUI({
  ggplotly(ggp())
})
```
````